# FileUtils: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Tags: ruby

I defined:

```
srcen = 'docs/tmp/en-US/html'
targeten = "#{home}/RubymineProjects/saigkill.github.com/docs/make_test_release/en-US/html"
```

I'm using:

```
FileUtils.cp_r(Dir["#{srcen}/*"], "#{targeten}")
```

But if I'm running this I'm getting an "ArgumentError", but I don't know why. `FileUtils.cp_r` has two arguments.

The full error is:

```
sascha@sascha-desktop:~/RubymineProjects/make_test_release$ rake publish_doc
Copying source html files to target git repository
rake aborted! ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
/home/sascha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/dir-0.1.2/lib/dir.rb:7:in `entries'
/home/sascha/RubymineProjects/make_test_release/Rakefile:150:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/sascha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/sascha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => publish_doc (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: paste the full error please

Comment: Can you runy `Dir["#{srcen}/*"]` and tell me the output ?

Comment: Hi Arup. The output gives nothing: sascha@sascha-desktop:~/RubymineProjects/make_test_release$ rake publish_doc
Copying source html files to target git repository
The Dir["#{srcen}/*"] was placed directly after the puts

Comment: Join [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79959/r-o-r) please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When pasting in error messages, it really helps us help you if you turn *off* word wrap before copying and pasting the text. The full lines are important, and when they run together it takes a lot longer to decipher where the real line starts and stops are.

Comment: Arup Rakshit helps me. The hint was: Dir["#{srcen}/*.*"] With that one my rake task works, Thank @Arup